# Decimal doesn't get converted to int

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having this code:

```py
from decimal import Decimal


class IntegList(list):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(int(other), int) and not isinstance(int(self), int):
            raise TypeError
        return self + other

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(int(other), int) and not isinstance(int(self), int):
            raise TypeError
        self += other
        return self
```

I'm trying to append a `Decimal` to the list:

```py
l = IntegList([2, 3, 5])
l.append(Decimal(9))
```

but ending up with the `Decimal(9)` not converted to `int`:

```
print(l)
# [2, 3, 5, Decimal('9')]
```

Also, if I define any properties/methods inside the class, they raise `TypeError` when processing the Decimal object.

How to cast the Decimal (and other types, like floats) to `int` properly?

Comment: Why should it convert it to integer? `append()` doesn't call `__add__` or `__iadd__`.

Comment: `int(Decimal('9'))` → `9`

Comment: I don't understand `not isinstance(int(self), int)`. `self` is an `IntegList` instance, you can't convert a list to `int`.

Comment: `isinstance(int(thing), int)` will always either error out or be trivially true, that seems weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `append()` to convert the value to an integer, you need to define an `append()` method in your class. Then it can call the superclass's method to do the actual appending.

```
def append(self, value):
    super().append(int(value))
```

The `__add__` method is used for implementing `l + something`, and `__iadd__` is for `l += something`. For a list, `something` needs to be another list, so you'll need to loop over its elements to convert them to `int`.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    other = [int(x) for x in other]
    return super().__add__(other)

def __iadd__(self, other):
    other = [int(x) for x in other]
    return super().__iadd__(other)
```